# Using selenium C#, How can I download Files in IE11?

Tags: c#, selenium, internet-explorer

I am trying to download files in IE11 for an automated test. My scripts are written using selenium in C#. So, I have search a lot but all the answers that I see that might work are on java or directed to Firefox (which makes no sense).

So I have tried to remove the save prompt from IE11 but I found not luck in that
And I can't find and alternative to Robot for C#

Comment: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/15271/8779

Comment: It worked. But I didn not use the {TAB} since it was kind of messy and didn't work every time. So I used System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("%S"); that is the shortcut alt+S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up using System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("%S"); after the popup appears